# Filtering Realm data in UITableView with 2 criteria

Tags: swift, search, filter, realm

hoping the awesome people of Stackoverflow can help with this:

I have a realm object with this structure:

```
class GasFile : Object {
@objc dynamic var gasFilename : String = ""
@objc dynamic var gasCategory : String? = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "gasFilename"
}}
```

and a search criteria of the following: (broken!)

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
        if searchText == "" {GasFileSearchResults = realm.objects(GasFile.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "gasFilename", ascending: true) }
        else {
            GasFileSearchResults = realm.objects(GasFile.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "gasFilename", ascending: true).filter("(gasFilename CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (gasCategory CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText!)
        }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

I can get it to work with one query of `gasFilename`, but I think I am making a mistake around the multiple criteria of 'gasFilename' and `gasCategory`... anyone help me out... thank you - going in circles!

Comment: Use NSPredicate.

Comment: I tried that El Tomato - I am writing in Swift so not sure how to implement NSPredicate for what I need to do.  Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add one more `searchText!`

```
realm.objects(GasFile.self)
    .sorted(byKeyPath: "gasFilename", ascending: true)
    .filter("(gasFilename CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (gasCategory CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText!, searchText!)
```

Comment: OMG - of course!! Anton Belousov you are awesome.... thank you so much!!!